# Cannot get Print button to work in Twitter Bootstrap modal popup from Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I followed the Answer at the question "Twitter Bootstrap: Print content of modal window" but I have not yet been able to get anything to print. I am using PHP to loop through and display several images in my Carousel, and can correctly display a clicked image in a Modal, but when the Print button on the Modal is clicked, nothing happens and I get no error message.

My Modal code:

```
<?php
$launch_cnt = 0;
// Get images again for building modals
$media2 = Media::find_by_sql($sql);
foreach($media2 as $media2): 
    $launch_cnt++;
    $launch = "launch" . $launch_cnt;
        ?> 
        <section id=<?php echo $launch; ?> class="modal hide fade">
          <header class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </header>

          <div id="printThis">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img src="../<?php echo $media2->image_path(); ?>"  />
            </div>
          </div>

          <footer class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnPrint">Print</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </footer>
        </section>
    <?php  
    endforeach;
?>
```

I have implemented the JS code and the CSS code as per the instructions pointed to in the Answer at http://jsfiddle.net/95ezN/3/

I have done some testing and it seems the problem is somewhere in my Javascript. If I use this code (placed just before the closing  tag):

```
<script>
alert("Hello World!");

document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
  printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
  window.print();
}
</script>
```

then the Alert popup of "Hello World!" is displayed, which tells me basically that I got there. But, if I include the required function named printElement, the Alert popup does not get displayed, so the JS is not getting executed at all. The complete JS with the function is:

```
<script>
alert("Hello World!");

document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
  printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
  window.print();
}

function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}  ​
</script>
```

Comment: For starters, you're mising a closing `?>` tag after you declare your `$launch` variable.

Comment: @Adam: there is no missing ?> tag. The PHP continues after declaring the $launch variable with a comment and then continues, so there is no problem with the code in regard to that, but thanks.

Comment: then you need an echo before your `section` tag

Comment: @Adam: not sure I follow you...why is an echo statement needed?

Comment: @Adam: sorry, I see what you are referring to now. My closing ?> tag is actually there but was removed by accident when I was copying and pasting my code to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The part responsible for showing the Print dialog is:

```
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
    window.print();
}
```

You could also change your html to:

```
 <button id="btnPrint" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Comment: Adam: there is no missing ?> tag. The PHP continues after declaring the $launch variable with a comment and then continues, so there is no problem with that.rsymek

Comment: @ryzmek: OK, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it results in printing a blank page.

Comment: So that's another different problem. Probably with your css

Comment: Still no luck. Anybody have any ideas?